# Leaflet marker animations tools

Tags: jquery, css, animation, d3.js, leaflet

I have a problem with an understanding of what tools me need use for writing animation for my map. I need to implement a trace of the object that you could click on each trace element and find out detailed information. I understand that the question of abstract, but I want to find at least some grounding, because after the analysis of ready plugins Github some writing on a leaflet ("css3"), some use jQuery or D3 library. Maybe someone has implemented a similar problem and can tell me the optimize way to solve this problem.

This is my Example marker view: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4SvTc9hw55PdS0yRkF5OC0yQUU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you are a novice a web-development world cruel. Since I did not have experience in web development animation in the leaflet, complete plugin in Github did not fit me and were too complicated. Me very helped a tutorial, where the animation using leaflet + jQuery function to update the animation. This construction simplified and easy customization.

Links are tutorial: http://www.jeroen-van-der-veen.com/creating-an-animated-leaflet-marker-with-css-transitions-and-sprites-part-1/